# Password verification failed while generating signed bundle for my android app

Tags: android-studio, gradle

Now I need to enter key store password and key password every time I generate a signed bundle even with a checked "Remember passwords".
It seems to appear with my new configuration of Android Studio 4.2 and Gradle 4.2.0

With the remembered passwords, I now got as the result of generating bundle "Password verification failed"
With re-entering the passwords, the generation goes fine.

What went wrong ?

**Update** : new version 4.2.1 of Android Studio. Still I can't build two releases in a row :

```
21:29   Executing tasks: [:app:bundleRelease] in project D:\Android Studio Projects\Acme

21:30   Gradle build finished in 52 s 8 ms

21:30   Generate Signed Bundle
            App bundle(s) generated successfully for module 'Acme.app' with 1 build variant:
            Build variant 'release': locate or analyze the app bundle.

21:30   Executing tasks: [:app:bundleRelease] in project D:\Android Studio Projects\Acme

21:31   Gradle build failed in 34 s 262 ms

21:31   Generate Signed Bundle: Errors while building Bundle file. You can find the errors in the 'Messages' view.
```

> Execution failed for task ':app:signReleaseBundle'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.FinalizeBundleTask$BundleToolRunnable
> Failed to read key acme_alias_name from store "D:\Android Studio Projects\acme\app\my-release-key.keystore": Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

Comment: It might be a bug, I have the same problem.

Comment: I also have the same problem (with android studio 4.2). Also had a lot of random crashes in some libraries after updating to AS 4.2, totally out of the blue, so I am pretty sure they screwed up something in update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my point of view, this issue is closed with Android Studio Artic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 version

Answer (score 5):

It's a bug introduced in the last studio version.  Worked fine for years, with this version after generating a signed APK changing projects or modules results in this error on the next APK generation.  They're corrupting the passwords, it's nothing to do with the file name.

Comment: idd, this is happening since 4.2. You have to add your passwords again, and it will work until you close Android Studio.

Comment: Well no, it'll happen many times in the same session without closing.  The other suggestion about removing special characters isn't much good either - why should I need to weaken my password, and why should it be broken now when it worked before.  Somebody there screwed up and needs a coding skills refresher if they want to play with password files...

Comment: I can confirm it is a bug in Android Studio 4.2 - started happening after update. Also, it is quite random - it does not work until closing as @S0und says, I side with Mike, it is random and for me it fails approximately every other or every third time from some weird reasons. And on top of that I have a lot of random crashes in my apk, from some of libraries (mainly gson) after updating to AS 4.2 - my code nor gson version have not changed, so for sure its a bug of android studio....They screwed up something majorly in 4.2 update

Comment: It's a bug. I downgraded to Android Studio 4.1 and it builds just fine (without any modification).

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your keystore file name without any special characters and numbers because I also faced same problem, in my case my keystore file name with underscore, I removed the underscore and tried, apk was build successfully. Try this and let us know.

Comment: I remove hypens from my keystore file name and there it is 3 generated signed bundle in a row ! Thanks for this easy bypass.

Comment: The bypass failed today. Need to input again and again passwords.